# Having a trouble to applying sass css in react component

Tags: jquery, html, css, reactjs

I am new in web development If can't explain the problem correctly, please post a comment so at least I can tell more.

Thanks a million in advance will appreciate if anyone can give me a little help

I have an HTML structure where I am trying to apply some CSS which is not working some reason.

I checked the same HTML and CSS in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2gsz3ct/) and Code-pen it work perfectly but when I applied the same thing in my react component it's doesn't show up anything

My code:

```css
/*
    Common 
*/

.wizard,
.tabcontrol {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wizard a,
.tabcontrol a {
  outline: 0;
}

.wizard ul,
.tabcontrol ul {
  list-style: none !important;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wizard ul>li,
.tabcontrol ul>li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Accessibility */

.wizard>.steps .current-info,
.tabcontrol>.steps .current-info {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}

.wizard>.content>.title,
.tabcontrol>.content>.title {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}


/*
    Wizard
*/

.wizard>.steps {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.wizard.vertical>.steps {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

.wizard>.steps .number {
  font-size: 1.429em;
}

.wizard>.steps>ul>li {
  width: 25%;
}

.wizard>.steps>ul>li,
.wizard>.actions>ul>li {
  float: left;
}

.wizard.vertical>.steps>ul>li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.wizard>.steps a,
.wizard>.steps a:hover,
.wizard>.steps a:active {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em;
  padding: 1em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard>.steps .disabled a,
.wizard>.steps .disabled a:hover,
.wizard>.steps .disabled a:active {
  background: #f3f4fa;
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: default;
}

.wizard>.steps .current a,
.wizard>.steps .current a:hover,
.wizard>.steps .current a:active {
  background: #008cff;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}

.wizard>.steps .done a,
.wizard>.steps .done a:hover,
.wizard>.steps .done a:active {
  background: #9dc8e2;
  color: #fff;
}

.wizard>.steps .error a,
.wizard>.steps .error a:hover,
.wizard>.steps .error a:active {
  background: #fd3550;
  color: #fff;
}

.wizard>.content {
  background: #f3f4fa;
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em;
  min-height: 35em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard.vertical>.content {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2.5% 0.5em 2.5%;
  width: 65%;
}

.wizard>.content>.body {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  padding: 2.5%;
}

.wizard>.content>.body ul {
  list-style: disc !important;
}

.wizard>.content>.body ul>li {
  display: list-item;
}

.wizard>.content>.body>iframe {
  border: 0 none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wizard>.content>.body input {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.wizard>.content>.body input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wizard>.content>.body input.error {
  background: rgb(251, 227, 228);
  border: 1px solid #fbc2c4;
  color: #8a1f11;
}

.wizard>.content>.body label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.wizard>.content>.body label.error {
  color: #8a1f11;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.wizard>.actions {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}

.wizard.vertical>.actions {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 2.5%;
  width: 95%;
}

.wizard>.actions>ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}

.wizard>.actions>ul>li {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.wizard.vertical>.actions>ul>li {
  margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}

.wizard>.actions a,
.wizard>.actions a:hover,
.wizard>.actions a:active {
  background: #008cff;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wizard>.actions .disabled a,
.wizard>.actions .disabled a:hover,
.wizard>.actions .disabled a:active {
  background: #f3f4fa;
  color: #aaa;
}

.wizard>.loading {}

.wizard>.loading .spinner {}


/*
    Tabcontrol
*/

.tabcontrol>.steps {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.tabcontrol>.steps>ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 6px 0 0 0;
  top: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tabcontrol>.steps>ul>li {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 2px 0 0;
  padding: 1px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.tabcontrol>.steps>ul>li:hover {
  background: #edecec;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabcontrol>.steps>ul>li.current {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 0 none;
  padding: 0 0 1px 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.tabcontrol>.steps>ul>li>a {
  color: #5f5f5f;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0 none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tabcontrol>.steps>ul>li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tabcontrol>.steps>ul>li.current>a {
  padding: 15px 30px 10px 30px;
}

.tabcontrol>.content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.tabcontrol>.content>.body {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  padding: 2.5%;
}

.tabcontrol>.content>.body ul {
  list-style: disc !important;
}

.tabcontrol>.content>.body ul>li {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<div id="wizard-vertical" role="application" class="wizard clearfix vertical">
  <div class="steps clearfix">
    <ul role="tablist">
      <li role="tab" class="first current" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true">
        <a id="wizard-vertical-t-0" href="#wizard-vertical-h-0" aria-controls="wizard-vertical-p-0">
          <span class="current-info audible">current step: </span>
          <span class="number">1.</span> Account</a>
      </li>
      <li role="tab" class="done" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
        <a id="wizard-vertical-t-1" href="#wizard-vertical-h-1" aria-controls="wizard-vertical-p-1">
          <span class="number">2.</span> Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li role="tab" class="done" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
        <a id="wizard-vertical-t-2" href="#wizard-vertical-h-2" aria-controls="wizard-vertical-p-2">
          <span class="number">3.</span> Hints</a>
      </li>
      <li role="tab" class="last done" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
        <a id="wizard-vertical-t-3" href="#wizard-vertical-h-3" aria-controls="wizard-vertical-p-3">
          <span class="number">4.</span> Finish</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="content clearfix">
    <h3 id="wizard-vertical-h-0" tabindex="-1" class="title current">Account</h3>
    <section id="wizard-vertical-p-0" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="wizard-vertical-h-0" class="body current" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>User name *</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label> Password *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Confirm Password *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-12">(*) Mandatory</label>
      </div>
    </section>
    <h3 id="wizard-vertical-h-1" tabindex="-1" class="title">Profile</h3>
    <section id="wizard-vertical-p-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="wizard-vertical-h-1" class="body" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label> First name *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label> Last name *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-12">(*) Mandatory</label>
      </div>
    </section>

    <h3 id="wizard-vertical-h-2" tabindex="-1" class="title">Hints</h3>
    <section id="wizard-vertical-p-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="wizard-vertical-h-2" class="body" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <ul>
            <li>Jonathan Smith </li>
            <li>Lab</li>
            <li>jonathan@example.com</li>
            <li>Your city, Cityname</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
    <h3 id="wizard-vertical-h-3" tabindex="-1" class="title">Finish</h3>
    <section id="wizard-vertical-p-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="wizard-vertical-h-3" class="body" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input id="checkbox-v" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="checkbox-v">
                                        I agree with the Terms and Conditions.
                                    </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

  </div>
  <div class="actions clearfix">
    <ul role="menu" aria-label="Pagination">
      <li class="disabled" aria-disabled="true">
        <a href="#previous" role="menuitem">Previous</a></li>
      <li aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" class="" style="display: block;">
        <a href="#next" role="menuitem">Next</a></li>
      <li aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <a href="#finish" role="menuitem">Finish</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Is a specific section not working? You need to be a bit more specific about what you expect to see vs what you are seeing.

Comment: You would need to share the React code, could be breaking for many reasons.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: when I am applying in react component it's not showing anything just giving this error: Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

Answer (score 1):

you have to link the css file to HTML document. You can use  where custom.css is the css file where you write styles. It works on jsfiddle because we dont have to define the link between css file and HTML document

Comment: I add all the CSS in a file called _dataset.scss  and added this file in the  sass folder and linked the file with main style sheet 
css file name: _dataset.scss
and linked to the main style sheet:  @import "./components/dataset";

Comment: are you using webpack or not